# NullPointerException using on-the-fly version of <gunzip> Ant task

Tags: java, ant, gunzip

The docs for [the `<gunzip>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unpack.html) say it has an on-the-fly version.

In my case this causes a NullPointerException:

```
>ant download
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Buildfile: ...\build.xml

download:

BUILD FAILED
...\build.xml:10: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Unpack.createDestFile(Unpack.java:144)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Unpack.validate(Unpack.java:139)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Unpack.execute(Unpack.java:164)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

`build.xml` is like follows:

```
<project name="MnistDigitsCorpus" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Скачивает файлы с хоста MNIST
    </description>

    <target name="download">
        <tstamp/>
        <gunzip dest=".">
            <url url="http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"/>
            <!--<url url="http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"/>
            <url url="http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"/>
            <url url="http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"/>-->
        </gunzip>

   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a (so far unknown) bug in Ant <= 1.9.6 that is triggered when extracting a non-filesystem resource.  At first I thought it would only happen if dest points to a directory and you could work around it by specifying the uncompressed target file name - but my tests show this only triggers a NullPointerException in a different place.

I've fixed the bug in Ant's master branch with git commit 7f0eeea[1] (and bunzip with 3c2ed13), but please file a bug report at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/ so we track it properly.

[1] https://github.com/apache/ant/commit/7f0eeea180a809355885bfcb6dbb65d5da307849

Comment: Thanks! Are you confirming this behavior?

Comment: I can clearly see why this happens by looking at the code, yes.  After writing some tests, I'm afraid even the workaround suggested will fail.